# How to get values for a chart with JavaScript in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I created an application with Django. In this system, there is an approval system. I created an `ApprovalProcess` model and it has a `beginning_date` field. I crated a chart for showing how many approval processes are started on which day? But I cannot fill this chart.

But I cannot figure it out how can I get approval process values as my data? the data that I want to display is `all_approvals` in my views.

**models.py**

```
class ApprovalProcess(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='starter')
    doc_id = models.ForeignKey(Pdf, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    highest_rank = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    last_approved = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='last_approved')
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def approval_context_processor(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        current_user = request.user

        rank_priority = RankPriority.objects.filter(rank=current_user.rank)
        priority = rank_priority[0].priority

        pend_list = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(status=priority)
        submit_list = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(user_id=current_user)

        userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=current_user)
        customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(company=userP[0].company)

        all_approvals = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(user_id__company=request.user.company)


        approved_reports = 0
        waiting_reports = 0
        for submit in submit_list:
            if submit.status - submit.highest_rank == 1:
                approved_reports += 1
            else:
                waiting_reports += 1

    else:
        pend_list = 0
        submit_list = 0

    context = {
        'pend_list': pend_list,
        'submit_list': submit_list,
        'approved_reports': approved_reports,
        'waiting_reports': waiting_reports,
        'customer_list': customer_list,
        'all_approvals': all_approvals
    }

    return context
```

**chart**

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div class="card-head-row">
                                <div class="card-title">User Statistics</div>
                                <div class="card-tools">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="chart-container" style="min-height: 375px">
                                <canvas id="statisticsChart"></canvas>
                            </div>
                            <div id="myChartLegend"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

...
...

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('statisticsChart').getContext('2d');

        var statisticsChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [
    
            ],
            datasets: [ {
                label: "Approval Processes",
                borderColor: '#f3545d',
                pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(243, 84, 93, 0.6)',
                pointRadius: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(243, 84, 93, 0.4)',
                legendColor: '#f3545d',
                fill: true,
                borderWidth: 2,
                data: [100, 184, 250, 203, 210, 231, 240, 278, 252, 312, 320, 374]
            }, ]
        },
        options : {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltips: {
                bodySpacing: 4,
                mode:"nearest",
                intersect: 0,
                position:"nearest",
                xPadding:10,
                yPadding:10,
                caretPadding:10
            },
            layout:{
                padding:{left:5,right:5,top:15,bottom:15}
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontStyle: "500",
                        beginAtZero: false,
                        maxTicksLimit: 5,
                        padding: 10
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        drawTicks: false,
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        zeroLineColor: "transparent"
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        padding: 10,
                        fontStyle: "500"
                    }
                }]
        },
        legendCallback: function(chart) {
            var text = [];
            text.push('<ul class="' + chart.id + '-legend html-legend">');
            for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
                text.push('<li><span style="background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[i].legendColor + '"></span>');
                if (chart.data.datasets[i].label) {
                    text.push(chart.data.datasets[i].label);
                }
                text.push('</li>');
            }
            text.push('</ul>');
            return text.join('');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Just use your context variables in your template and use those to fill `data` in `datasets`. Are you having problems with that?

Comment: @yvesonline yes. I cannot fill the chart with my values.

Comment: I don't know where your data is coming from in the view. But assuming that it's in the `all_approvals` context variable then you just need to use this context variable in your template, i.e. `{{ all_approvals }}`. You'll need it formatted so you can think about formatting it in Python (e.g. `", ".join()` if it's a list) and then passing the correctly formatted string via the context.

Comment: @yvesonline Yes I want to display `all_approvals` I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know which data you want to get from `ApprovalProcess` model but suppose you want to get `highest_rank`  field to pass it to data chart

you code will be like this :

```
import json

def approval_context_processor(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        current_user = request.user

    rank_priority = RankPriority.objects.filter(rank=current_user.rank)
    priority = rank_priority[0].priority

    pend_list = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(status=priority)
    submit_list = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(user_id=current_user)

    userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=current_user)
    customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(company=userP[0].company)

    all_approvals = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(user_id__company=request.user.company)


    approved_reports = 0
    waiting_reports = 0
    for submit in submit_list:
        if submit.status - submit.highest_rank == 1:
            approved_reports += 1
        else:
            waiting_reports += 1

else:
    pend_list = 0
    submit_list = 0

context = {
    'pend_list': pend_list,
    'submit_list': submit_list,
    'approved_reports': approved_reports,
    'waiting_reports': waiting_reports,
    'customer_list': customer_list,
    'all_approvals': json.dumps([e.highest_rank  for e in all_approvals])
}

return context
```

then you get your data in template like this :

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('statisticsChart').getContext('2d');

        var statisticsChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [
    
            ],
            datasets: [ {
                label: "Approval Processes",
                borderColor: '#f3545d',
                pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(243, 84, 93, 0.6)',
                pointRadius: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(243, 84, 93, 0.4)',
                legendColor: '#f3545d',
                fill: true,
                borderWidth: 2,
                data: {{ all_approvals|safe }}
            }, ]
        },
        options : {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltips: {
                bodySpacing: 4,
                mode:"nearest",
                intersect: 0,
                position:"nearest",
                xPadding:10,
                yPadding:10,
                caretPadding:10
            },
            layout:{
                padding:{left:5,right:5,top:15,bottom:15}
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontStyle: "500",
                        beginAtZero: false,
                        maxTicksLimit: 5,
                        padding: 10
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        drawTicks: false,
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        zeroLineColor: "transparent"
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        padding: 10,
                        fontStyle: "500"
                    }
                }]
        },
        legendCallback: function(chart) {
            var text = [];
            text.push('<ul class="' + chart.id + '-legend html-legend">');
            for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
                text.push('<li><span style="background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[i].legendColor + '"></span>');
                if (chart.data.datasets[i].label) {
                    text.push(chart.data.datasets[i].label);
                }
                text.push('</li>');
            }
            text.push('</ul>');
            return text.join('');
        }
    }
});
```